# Github Actions - How to compile SCSS to CSS in CI build time?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am unsure how people are compiling scss files to css files in Github Actions' CI build time . Here is my way of doing it. Please let me know if it's the wrong way to approach it.

**Here is my github repo:**
https://github.com/mattfrancis888/gh_actions_heroku

**Here is my project directory**

```
.github
  -> workflows
      -> main.yml
src
  pages
   ->app.ts
  scss 
   -> main.scss
   -> main.css (untracked in git & not pushed to remote repoistory, it is used locally
  ; github actions should compile the main.scss file and create a main.css file at CI build time)
package.json
```

**Here is my main.yml**, I am following [Sass Build Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sass-build#quick-start) as the template to convert .scss to. css at CI build time. (SASS Build Action seems to have very little activity & support on it)

```
build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: Checkout source Git branch
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
          with:
            ref: main
            fetch-depth: 10
            submodules: true

        - name: Compile CSS from SCSS files
          uses: gha-utilities/sass-build@v0.4.7
          with:
              source: /src/scss/main.scss #I have removed the / in /src and it is still failing
              destination:  /src/scss/main.css 

            #deploys to heroku (unrelated to SASS Build Action)
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 # This is the action
          with:
              heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
              heroku_app_name: "ga" #Must be unique in Heroku
              heroku_email: "a88@gmail.com"
```

When I use SASS to try to compile .scss files to .csss files,  I am receiving this error in github action's step at "***Compile CSS from SCSS files***" :

```
Error: /src/scss/main.scss: no such file or directory
    at Object._newRenderError (/home/runner/work/_actions/gha(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10) {
  formatted: 'Error: /src/scss/main.scss: no such file or directory',
  status: 3
}
```

**Update**

This is fixed by @'Matthias' answer by changing the main.yml to

```
          with:
          source: ./src/scss/main.scss
          destination:  ./src/scss/main.css
```

However, I am met with the following error now:

***Here is the output that is working in step: Compile SCSS files to CSS:***

```
Run gha-utilities/sass-build@v0.4.7
    Warning: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './src/scss/main.css'
    Attempting to write to file path -> ./src/scss/main.css
    Wrote file -> ./src/scss/main.css
```

This is the error in the next step when trying to deploy it to heroku.

```
    remote: Failed to compile.        
remote: remote: ./pages/_app.tsxremote: 
Module not found: Can't resolve '../src/scss/main.css' in '/tmp/build_9673181c/pages'
```

It looks like main.csss is not created in src/scss at the CI build time. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put an . before the /?
As a dot means from right here go there. ;-)

So it would be:

```
./src/scss/main.scss
```

Comment: Hey @Matthias Kluth, your answer worked! However, I am met with another error after changing that, I have updated the post :)!